# Typedef renaming classes for cross platform compatibility

Tags: c++, typedef

So I want cross-platform compatibility for my library with MacOS and Windows. To achieve this I have almost identical classes for each platform: `MyClassMacOS` & `MyClassWin`. At compile time, I want to use only one of them and rename it so the user only sees `MyClass` and I am trying to do it like this:

```
header.h

#if __APPLE__
#   include "MyClassMacOS"
    namespace n {
        typedef n::MyClassMacOS MyClass
    }


#if __WIN__
#  include "MyClassWin.h"
    namespace n {
        typedef n::MyClassWin MyClass
    }
```

I have the typedefs wrapped in a namespace to preserve the namespace the original MyClass is wrapped in.

The problem is that the code-completion system is displaying both the original definition and the new typedef definition. Is there a way to hide the original definition and just show the new one? Perhaps I should look into a different way for achieving cross platform?

Things I have considered:

- renaming MyClassWin and MyClassMacOS to something else... but then it will still show up in the hints and might confuse the user.
- renaming MyClassWin and MyClassMacOS to __MyClassWin and __MyClassMacOS, it'll still show up in the code completion, but only if you start typing "_". However, seems like __ names are reserved for the compiler.

Comment: Simpler idea, if you can get away with it. Same header and class definition for both. Different implementation files, maybe with the assistance of [PIMPL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). Let the IDE and linker take care of which implementation file you use.

Comment: How much of the implementations of the two classes are different? Do they share *any* common functionality? Perhaps inheritance, polymorhpism and factory functions could be a possible solution?

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the suggestion, I will look into PIMPL to see the feasibility. Can you can clarify what you mean by "Same header and class definition" but "different implementation files"? Don't class definitions go into the implementation files?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude They share the same public methods, but the implementation to achieve that is vastly different. Thank you for the suggestion of polymorphism, I think the biggest drawback to that approach for me is that it seems like there is no way for the user to directly create an instance of my object, so I need to provide a factory method.

Comment: Very often the interface, the class definition, doesn't need to change much when aiming for portability. Whether Mac, PC, Linux or Amiga, what you're going to do with an object shouldn't change. The member functions should not change. The definitions of the functions, they can change quite a bit, but thy're hidden in a cpp file  where the user doesn't care how different they are, so long as the visible behaviour is the same. That leaves member variables. C++ does a good job abstracting most type differences between the platforms, and the rest can usually be hidden by PIMPL.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for the clarification! I looked more into PIMPL (which I've been avoiding for a while), and it seems like the way to go. PIMPL can also hide my implementation headers which was another problem I have also been trying to solve.

Comment: @user4581301 one more thing, when you say "Let the IDE and linker take care of which implementation file you use", don't I have to provide in my cmakelists which implementation I want to compile?

Comment: Yes. Whatever build tool you use has to be either configured to or taught to link the correct files

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to switch the implementation completely, without letting the other one exist, since you can only have one per platform:

```
#if __APPLE__

struct MyClass {
    auto function() -> int;
};

#elif __WIN__

struct MyClass {
    auto function() -> int;
};

#endif
```

But for the sake of organizing your code, you can put them in different headers:

myclass_apple.h:

```
struct MyClass {
    auto function() -> int;

private:
    AppleSpecificStuff stuff;
};
```

myclass_win.h:

```
struct MyClass {
    auto function() -> int;

private:
    WinSpecificStuff stuff;
};
```

myclass.h:

```
#if __APPLE__
#include "myclass_apple.h"
#elif __WIN__
#include "myclass_win.h"
#endif
```

Then, you can put the different implementation in different `.cpp` files. In your build system, simply compile the one that is relevant to the current platform.

Comment: awesome, thank you for the example. correct me if I am wrong, this is the pimpl idiom?

Comment: @seanngpack This is not the pimpl idiom. The pimpl idiom hide the actual implementation in a cpp file, and expose the pointer of an incomplete type in the header. My answer is link-time polymorphism: the build system switch between implementations.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I see. Thank you!